# Why is my average CTR different from my overall CTR?

Tags: mean, ratio

Here's some sample data:

```
Views    Clicks  CTR 
13958    104     0.75% 
215395   1091    0.51%
809432   2975    0.37% 
1229979  3675    0.30% 
1821167  4255    0.23%
2191041  5039    0.23% 
2338723  4033    0.17% 
2429408  4140    0.17%
2397012  4006    0.17%
```

- Total views is: 13,446,115
- Total clicks is: 29,318

Therefore I have an overall clickthrough rate of 0.21%

However, the average of all the clickthroughs in the table is: 0.32%

Why are the two so different? Shouldn't they be the same?

Comment: Suppose you add another line with 1 view and 1 click for a CTR of 100%.  What is the new average of CTR?  Do you think that average would be a reasonable representation of the data?

Comment: That is a very good point